# how to embed "font, color & font size" in cells of TAB delimited file just like '=TEXT" is treated

Tags: excel, text, formula, embed

I am importing TAB delimited file into excel. I know how to use '=text' to format dates, large numbers, etc but my work require to have the headings in "Different font & font sizes".  
Can I embed the font & font size in my heading CELLs?  So when excel open the file, it will be treated like the way excel treat cells with embedded '=Text"?

Answer (score 0):

which excel Version do you use? Of you use 2016 Check try the Import with  power-query (Get and Transform) .
You will get the imported data as table. There you can format the header like you want. 
Best regards
Chris

Comment: Thank you Chris; my excel is 2016.  However can you please elaborate and if possible send me the link.

Comment: You can find Information [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-external-data-sources-Power-Query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a)
 here, how to connect to excternal Data Source (with PQ).